# Understanding JSF-validators. Do I really need one in this case?

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

I'm on Mojarra 2.1.

I have the input-element:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.name} />
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.doSave()} />
```

where

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean{

    private String name;

    @ManagedProperty(name="myService")
    private MyService myService;

    public void doSave(){
         if(myService.isUnique(name))
              myService.save(name);
    }
}

public interface MyService{
    public boolean isUnique(String name);
    public void save(String name);
}
```

Now, I tend to write a JSF-validator performing the validation for uniqueness of the name, therefore making the code more concise (there will no more this unique-name checking in the action method).

But I'm not sure if such using of JSF-validators is appropriate in such a context. In the uniqueness validation I have `Service`'s method called, therefore I mix data-access with view-technology. It seems like a thing I should avoid.

***Question:*** Should we avoid writing JSF-validators using data-access? If so, what would be a good way to perform such checking?

Comment: @Tiny So, you think it's correct to do such validation within a JSF-validator. But what about the fact that we're mixing data-access and view-technology? Isn't that considered bad?

Comment: @Tiny Indeed, you're absolutely right. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @BalusC Excellent point, that's exactly what I wanted to learn. So yes, it's a dupe.